# Vertically aligning figures inside table

Tags: tables, floats, minipage, multirow

I want to produce a table that includes figures of different heights.  To the right of each figure there are multiple rows of text.

The best I can produce so far is:

[image: example]

Which has two flaws:

1. Both figures are not vertically aligned.
2. The second figure falls outside the table (I would like for lines 3 and 4 to be spaced farther apart from the rulers above and below, so as to create enough vertical space).

Is there a way to have LaTeX **automatically** center the figures and add vertical space when necesary?

The code I used is:

```
\documentclass[letter,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace} \doublespacing
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
\textbf{Figure} & \textbf{Descriptions} \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig1.jpg}} & line 1 \\
                                                       & line 2 \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig2.jpg}} & line 3 \\
                                                       & line 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And the test figures are:
[image: fig1.jpg]
[image: fig2.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

You can insert an invisible rule in the second column to change the cell height. A second solution is not to use `\multirow`, but the adjacent end of rows in a `\makecell` command, which allows for line breaks inside cells:

```
\documentclass[letter,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace} \doublespacing
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, booktabs, multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
\textbf{Figure} & \textbf{Descriptions} \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}[-0.7ex]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig1.jpg}} & line 1 \\
                                                       & line 2 \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig2.jpg}} & line 3 \\
                                                       & line 4 \rule{0pt}{8ex}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
\textbf{Figure} & \textbf{Descriptions} \\
\hline
  \raisebox{-0.45\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig1.jpg}} & \makecell{ line 1 \\ line 2} \\
    \midrule
    \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig2.jpg}} &\makecell{ line 3 \\ line 4} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's the output I want, but I need for this to be done automatically (i.e., no manual fiddling with the exact ruler size, as I need to create many of these tables).

Comment: @scaramouche: I've added another solution, more automatic. It uses a `\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics{…}}` command, which should  theoretically give an automatic vertical centring, but may require some adjustment, probably due to a bad bounding box of the graphic file.

Comment: Thanks, this is better, but still requires manual adjustment (via the `raisebox`).  The `adjustbox` approach by @Zarko is more automatic, although it does not provide perfect alignment.  So far, there's no perfect approach.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, where is exploited `makecell` macro from `makecell` package and used `valign=m` macro from package `adjustbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letter,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace} \doublespacing
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow,}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
\textbf{Figure}     &   \textbf{Descriptions}                                             \\
    \midrule
\includegraphics[width=30mm,height=15mm,valign=m]{example-image-a}  &   \makecell{line 1 \\
                                                                         line 2}        \\
    \midrule
\includegraphics[width=15mm,height=30mm,valign=m]{example-image-b}  &   \makecell{line 3 \\
                                                                         line 4}        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is almost right, except that the figure is not perfectly aligned (there's slightly more white space on one side).

Comment: How you measure this? Images are perfectly centered in table, i.e.: better centering of cell content in table is not possible. Please elaborate your claim.

Comment: @scaramouche, any news?